# Prove that this series diverges or converges: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

*Determine if this series diverges or converges:*
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}$$
I tried to find a series to compare with this one. I calculated the sum by programming the series with very large numbers and it seems that the series diverges, so I tried to compare it but I didn't find any. Any suggestions? thank you in advance :)

Comment: *Hint:* What is the simplest *necessary* criterion for convergence?

Comment: What is the limit of the terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the terms of the series$$\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}=\frac{2^n}{2^n+n^3}+\frac{n}{2^n+n^3}$$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl[\frac{2^n}{2^n+n^3}\biggr]=1$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl[\frac{n}{2^n+n^3}\biggr]=0$

so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl[\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}\biggr]=1$

what happens when the terms of the series converge to a value $\ne0$?

Comment: I appreciate when people could explain why they downvote what I post.

Answer (score 1):

With *asymptotic analysis*:

$n, n^3\in o\bigl(2^n\bigr)$, so $2^n+n,\, 2^n+n^3\sim_\infty 2^n$, whence
$$\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}\sim_\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n}=1,$$
which shows the series diverges trivially.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{2^n+n}{2^n+n^3}=\frac{1+2^{-n} n}{1+2^{-n} n^3}$$
$$\log(a_n) \sim 2^{-n} n-2^{-n} n^3=2^{-n}n(1-n^2)$$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n) \sim 2^{-(n+1)} (n-4) n (n+1) > 0 \quad \forall n >4$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)} > 1$$

If you use $n=100$, using the exact definition of $a_n$, the exact value is
$$\frac{a_{21} } {a_{20}}=\frac{184651888304}{184064687179}=1.003190$$ while the approximation gives
$$\frac{a_{21} } {a_{20}}\sim e^{105/32768}=1.003209$$